Maui Application menu items are not displayed correctly
I have the following code and I don't understand why the menu entries are not displayed. I really have already tried a lot, but in my opinion this should work.

using System.Collections.Generic;
using Microsoft.Maui.Controls;

namespace SideManagementTool
{
    public class MenuItem
    {
        public string Icon { get; set; }
        public string Title { get; set; }
        public string Description { get; set; }
    }

    public partial class MainPage : ContentPage
    {
        public List<MenuItem> MenuItems { get; set; }

        public MainPage()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            // Define the menu items using local images
            MenuItems = new List<MenuItem>
            {
                new MenuItem { Icon = "icon_dashboard.png", Title = "Dashboard", Description = "Overview of activities" },
                new MenuItem { Icon = "icon_projects.png", Title = "Projects", Description = "Manage your projects" },
                new MenuItem { Icon = "icon_notifications.png", Title = "Notifications", Description = "Check notifications" },
                new MenuItem { Icon = "icon_analytics.png", Title = "Analytics", Description = "View analytics data" },
                new MenuItem { Icon = "icon_items.png", Title = "Items", Description = "Manage items" },
                new MenuItem { Icon = "icon_settings.png", Title = "Settings", Description = "Configure settings" }
            };

            // Set the BindingContext to self so that the XAML can access the properties
            BindingContext = this;
        }

        // Command for handling item click
        public Command<MenuItem> OnMenuItemClicked => new Command<MenuItem>((item) =>
        {
            DisplayAlert("Menu Clicked", $"You clicked on {item.Title}", "OK");
        });
    }
}

XAML
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2021/maui"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             x:Class="SideManagementTool.MainPage"
             BackgroundColor="#5AA1D7"
             Shell.NavBarIsVisible="False">

    <Grid RowDefinitions="*" ColumnDefinitions="Auto,*">

        <!-- Sidebar -->
        <Frame Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" 
               BackgroundColor="LightGray" 
               WidthRequest="250" 
               VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand"
               CornerRadius="0">

            <VerticalStackLayout Padding="10">
                <!-- Header -->
                <Label Text="CodingLab" FontSize="24" FontAttributes="Bold" HorizontalOptions="Center" />

                <!-- Menu Items List -->
                <CollectionView ItemsSource="{Binding MenuItems}" SelectionMode="None">
                    <CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <Grid Padding="10" ColumnDefinitions="Auto,*">
                                <!-- Icon -->
                                <Image Source="{Binding Icon}" WidthRequest="20" HeightRequest="20" VerticalOptions="Center" />

                                <!-- Text -->
                                <VerticalStackLayout Grid.Column="1" Spacing="2" Padding="10,0,0,0">
                                    <Label Text="{Binding Title}" FontSize="16" TextColor="Black" />
                                    <Label Text="{Binding Description}" FontSize="12" TextColor="Gray" />
                                </VerticalStackLayout>

                                <!-- Hover and Click Animations -->
                                <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                                    <VisualStateGroup x:Name="CommonStates">
                                        <VisualState x:Name="Normal" />
                                        <VisualState x:Name="PointerOver">
                                            <VisualState.Setters>
                                                <Setter TargetName="Grid" Property="BackgroundColor" Value="#E0E0E0" />
                                            </VisualState.Setters>
                                        </VisualState>
                                        <VisualState x:Name="Pressed">
                                            <VisualState.Setters>
                                                <Setter TargetName="Grid" Property="BackgroundColor" Value="#B0B0B0" />
                                            </VisualState.Setters>
                                        </VisualState>
                                    </VisualStateGroup>
                                </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>

                                <!-- Tap Gesture for Click Animation -->
                                <Grid.GestureRecognizers>
                                    <TapGestureRecognizer Command="{Binding Source={x:Reference Name=MainPage}, Path=OnMenuItemClicked}" />
                                </Grid.GestureRecognizers>
                            </Grid>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
                </CollectionView>
            </VerticalStackLayout>
        </Frame>

        <!-- Main Content -->
        <ContentView Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1" 
                     BackgroundColor="White" 
                     Padding="20"
                     VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand"
                     HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand">
            <Label Text="Content goes here" FontSize="24" 
                   HorizontalOptions="Center" 
                   VerticalOptions="Center" 
                   TextColor="Black" />
        </ContentView>

    </Grid>
</ContentPage>

I have tried to make my problem and my code as small as possible to get to the bottom of the problem.
Perhaps someone of you can help me further.

The first point is x:Reference markup extension
When you set the Binding Source using x:Reference, you should first set the x:Name of the ContentPage, like below, and then you can use x:Reference markup
<ContentPage xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2021/maui"
         ...
         BackgroundColor="#5AA1D7"
         Shell.NavBarIsVisible="False"
         x:Name="this">

...

<TapGestureRecognizer Command="{Binding Source={x:Reference Name=this}, Path=OnMenuItemClicked}" />

Please note that don't set the name to MainPage as it will throw the error.
Actually, you may also try using Relative Binding if you want,
<TapGestureRecognizer  Command="{Binding Source={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type local:MainPage}}, Path=OnMenuItemClicked}" />

this also works.
And don't forget to add the CommandParameter to the TapGesture, such as  CommandParameter="{Binding .}

The Second one is the use of VisualStateManager.
You have already defined the VisualStateManager on the Grid. So, you don't have to set the TargetName property.
<VisualState.Setters>
    <Setter Property="BackgroundColor" Value="#E0E0E0" />
</VisualState.Setters>

And if you want to set the TargetName, you should first set a x:Name to the Grid. Otherwise, it will not find the Grid control and throw an error.
<Grid x:Name="Grid" Padding="10" ColumnDefinitions="Auto,*">


The last suggestion is that using Border instead of Frame, as the doc says.
For more info, please refer to x:Reference markup extension, Visual states, Frame and Border.
Please let me know if you have any question!
